# How to check a checkbox in a default column list in sharepoint 2013 with powershell?

Tags: list, powershell, checkbox, sharepoint-2013

I have to write a script in powershell, and I'm new to it, to check specific checkbox when a sharepoint site is created. In a list, in sharepoint, we can go to list, change the display, and we can check the columns we want to display in the list.

I have this

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://mysite"
$spList  = $spWeb.Lists["MyList"]
$spList.Fields |ft title, internalname, id, type, hidden -AutoSize
```

I found the ones I want to check (example)

```
Title                                      InternalName
-----                                      ------------ 
Created By                                 Author
Modified By                                Editor
```

I looked at the properties with

```
$spList.Fields.GetField("Author")
```

but I didn't found the property to set the value to true. I also set the checkbox to true in sharepoint, executed the command again and do a compare to see if a property changed, but nothing changed.

I also tried to do :

```
Update($true)
```

on the field, on the list.

I want to check those checkbox with a powershell command, I have many lists where I have to do this, and I have to execute that script on many sites.

Thank you for your help

If you need more information, let me know. I didn't found what I was looking for, I tried many things, but nothing worked.
 (I couldn't post images..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After somme research, I found that I have to modify my View. I had some custom columns, so I had some code after that.

```
$spViews = $spList.Views["All Items"]
```

After, I did a try/catch statement with this

```
$spViews.ViewFields.Add($spList.Fields.getField("Author"))
$spViews.Update()
```

And it worked!

I went on my lists, and all my list were updated with "Created by" "Created" "Modified by" and "Modified". They were displayed in my view list.

Comment: So in PS terms, `$spViews` is a Sharepoint View object, an object of type blahblahblah.foofoofoo.barbarbar (probably ends in SharePoint.View).  `ViewFields` is a property of that object and `Add` is a method.  Same for `$spList` (object), `Fields` (Property), `getField` (method).  Use `Get-Member` to explore objects and their properties within PowerShell.  You're using a convention of putting 'sp' before your SharePoint object names, which is probably good form, but just know that it's optional.  I expect the SharePoint PowerShell module probably has view and list manipulation cmdlets.